# How can I declare an array which I dont know the Index No of items beforehand

Tags: php, arrays, nested, declaration

I'm trying to create an "unlimited" array, such as is going to get the inputed text from a form and separate its words into different indexes of the same array ($words[$j])

I've noticed I have to declare the array with "","" to declare the expected string values of each index, because I if only declare one of the indexes as a string it will be nesting sucesive arrays after the Firstone.

```
      <?php

        if(!empty($_GET['text'])){
          $text = $_GET['text'];
          $words = array("");
          $j = 0;
          for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i ++){
            $words[$j][$i] = $text[$i];
            if($text[$i] == " "){
              $j ++;
            }
            }
            print_r($words);
          }

      ?>

Array ( [0] => Big [1] => Array ( [4] => r [5] => e [6] => d [7] => ) [2] => Array ( [8] => R [9] => o [10] => c [11] => k [12] => e [13] => t ) )
```

vs

```
          $words = array("","","","","","","","");

Array ( [0] => Big [1] => red [2] => Rocket [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => )
```

I am aware this question may have been tackled in an unconventional way, so any reference to any material in order to guide me through my learning would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think if you create an empty array that will later be populated it may help

e.g:

```
$words = [];
```

Comment: be **careful**, this array declaration works in the greater version of  `PHP 5.3`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you mean if i get you correctly

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
```

**PHP**

```
if(!empty($_GET['text'])){
          $text = $_GET['text'];
          $N = count($text);
          for($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++){
            $words[] = $text[$i];
            }
            var_dump($words);
          }
```